# DependencyProperty Object not updating to UI

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection, dependency-properties, inotifypropertychanged

I am struggling with a dependencyproperty in a control. My dependencyproperty is an object which looks like this:

```
public class ChartGroupCollection : ObservableCollection<ChartGroup>, INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    public void ClearDirty()
    {
        foreach (var grp in base.Items)
        {
            foreach(var run in grp.ChartRuns.Where(x=>x.IsDirty))
            {
                run.IsDirty = false;
            }

            grp.IsDirty = false;
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool IsDirty  //dirty flag for save prompt
    {
        get
        {
            ....
        }
    }

} 

[Serializable]
public class ChartGroup : INotifyPropertyChanged
{ ... //various properties }
```

The DependencyProperty is set up as here (named Tree, which is instance of a ChartGroupCollection):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TreeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Tree", typeof(ChartGroupCollection), typeof(ChartsControl), new PropertyMetadata(OnTreeChanged));
    public ChartGroupCollection Tree
    {
        get { return (ChartGroupCollection)GetValue(TreeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TreeProperty, value); }
    }
 private static void OnTreeChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var Treee = sender as ChartsControl;
        if (e.OldValue != null)
        {
            var coll = (INotifyCollectionChanged)e.OldValue;
            coll.CollectionChanged -= Tree_CollectionChanged;
        }
        if (e.NewValue != null)
        {
            var coll = (ObservableCollection<ChartGroup>)e.NewValue;
            coll.CollectionChanged += Tree_CollectionChanged;
        }

    }

    private static void Tree_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as ChartsControl).OnTreeChanged();
    }

    void OnTreeChanged()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Do something...");  //RefreshCharts();
    }
```

I seem to be getting to the OnTreeChanged event only at creation of the object, but once i do other work (adding to lists inside ChartGroup or changing properties of ChartGroup objects or even deleting elements of the observablecollection it never seems to trigger a refresh event. I have tried several other methods of getting the dependencyproperty found online but no solution worked for me. I wonder if it is down to the intrinsic nature of my dependencyproperty object or an error from my side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sender` argument in your `Tree_CollectionChanged` handler is not the `ChartsControl` instance, but the collection that raised the CollectionChanged event.

The `Tree_CollectionChanged` method should not be static

```
private void Tree_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    OnTreeChanged();
}
```

and it should be attached and removed like this:

```
private static void OnTreeChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var control = sender as ChartsControl;
    var oldCollection = e.OldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
    var newCollection = e.NewValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;

    if (oldCollection != null)
    {
        oldCollection.CollectionChanged -= control.Tree_CollectionChanged;
    }

    if (newCollection != null)
    {
        newCollection.CollectionChanged += control.Tree_CollectionChanged;
    }
}
```

Note also that adding a CollectionChanged handler does not care for subscribing to PropertyChanged events of the collection elements. You would also have to attach or remove a PropertyChanged handler whenever an element is added to or removed from the collection. Take a look at the `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs.Action` property.

Comment: Thanks, you are right about the static. I am still stuck on control.TileLayerCollectionChanged what does it do and what code do i need to add to make it work? create a method stub?

Comment: That was just a copy&paste error from my code. Meanwhile I have edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the real speed in answering. Perfect